# Applying element tree to parse a complex xml structure

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm having trouble parsing the xml file below. Here's what I have tried;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<corpus name="P4P" version="1.0" lng="en" xmlns="http://clic.ub.edu/mbertran/formats/paraphrase-corpus"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://clic.ub.edu/mbertran/
formats/paraphrase-corpus http://clic.ub.edu/mbertran/formats/paraphrase-corpus.xsd">
    <snippets>
        <snippet id="16488"    source_description="type:plagiarism;plagiarism_reference:00061;
        offset:47727;length:182;source:P4P;wd_count:37">
        All art is imitation of nature.
        </snippet>

    </snippets>
</corpus>
```

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree
#root=xml.etree.ElementTree.parse("C:\\Users\\P4P_corpus\\P4P_corpus_v1.xml").getroot()
source=root.findall('snippets/snippet')
for details in source.findall:
    print details.get('source_description')
    print details.findtext
```

my output was empty

my desired output:

```
"type:plagiarism;plagiarism_reference:00061;
        offset:47727;length:182;source:P4P;wd_count:37"
```

and `All art is imitation of nature.`

I Would really appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: I don't believe that your output was empty for the code as posted. `snippets\snipet` would have raised an error at the very least.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, sorry I put the slash the wrong way, I'll edit the question now. But that output is what I got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prefix elements with the xml namespace. If you print root after parsing you'll get

```
   <Element '{http://clic.ub.edu/mbertran/formats/paraphrase-corpus}corpus' at 0x7ff7891f6390>
            ^       this part here is the full name                       ^
```

so to iterate over 'snippet' elements you first find 'snippets' element and the 'snippet' elements

```
for snippets in root.findall('{http://clic.ub.edu/mbertran/formats/paraphrase-corpus}snippets'):
    for s in snippets.findall('{http://clic.ub.edu/mbertran/formats/paraphrase-corpus}snippet'):
        print s.get('source_description')
```

you can read about handling namespaces @ https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces

Comment: good solution, it worked. Many thanks.